# SQL bookmarks - phpMyAdmin - is it possible to install separately?

Tags: phpmyadmin

We're using phpMyAdmin on our dev servers and it would be handy to have certain common SQL statements available to all developers (e.g. as SQL bookmarks).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the phpMyAdmin bookmark feature will help. Read some [general information](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/bookmark) or jump right in to the [usage instructions](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#bookmarks-where-can-i-store-bookmarks-why-can-t-i-see-any-bookmarks-below-the-query-box-what-is-this-variable-for).

Basically you'll need to configure the phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage in order to enable the feature, but then you'll have access to a checkbox to "Bookmark this query" when running an SQL query; once bookmarked you can run the bookmarked query by selecting it from the dropdown. You can even do some variable substitution through your query by putting `/*[VARIABLE]*/ in your query.